# How to use UIRemoteNotificationTypeVoIP?

Tags: ios, ios8, sip, voip

From documentation for setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: method of UIApplication:

> In iOS 8 and later, voice-over-IP (VoIP) apps register for UIRemoteNotificationTypeVoIP push notifications instead of using this method. Using push notifications eliminates the need for a timeout handler to check in with the VoIP service. Instead, when a calls arrives for the user, the VoIP service sends a VoIP push notification to the user’s device. Upon receiving this notification, the device launches or wakes the app as needed so that it can handle the incoming call.

But I can't find anything about it. Is this a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If someone is also confused by this documentation, they probably mean **PushKit Framework** and PKPushTypeVoIP presented in WWDC 2014, Writing Energy Efficient Code, Part 2

Comment: Is it possible to handle UIRemoteNotificationTypeVoIP without using PushKit? Our app still isn't 64 bit (thanks to our cross-platform VOIP library, which is yet to be rewritten) and we still support iOS 7.

Comment: No, there is no UIRemoteNotificationTypeVoIP, it's just mistake in documentation. There is only PushKit